# Values don't add up in simple calculation

Tags: kotlin, timestamp

I am trying to build an event calendar. Every event has a date and then a start time.

The way I am building it is I get the base timestamp for the date once the user picks one, and then as they pick the hour and the minute I add to the timestamp the appropriate amount of milliseconds to change the timestamp.

For some reason I really don't get, all the values come out fine but they just don't add together. There are no errors, the base timestamp value just stays the same.

So, in a previous operation I got the base timestamp which works just fine, and then using this code I want to add the milliseconds.

```
    startTime.setOnTimeChangedListener { _, hourOfDay, minute ->

        if (baseMillis != null) {
            startDate =
                baseMillis!! + (hourOfDay.toLong() * 3600000) + (minute.toLong() * 60000)

            Log.d("timeestart", hourOfDay.toString())
            Log.d("timeestart", minute.toString())
            Log.d("timeestart", baseMillis.toString())
            Log.d("timeestart", (hourOfDay.toLong() * 3600000).toString())
            Log.d("timeestart", (minute.toLong() * 60000).toString())
            Log.d("timeestart", (baseMillis!! + (hourOfDay.toLong() * 3600000) + (minute.toLong() * 60000)).toString())
            Log.d("timeestart", startDate.toString())
        }
    }
```

And this is what I get printed:

```
2019-09-17 08:55:37.568 8080-8080/com.republicera D/timeestart: 9
2019-09-17 08:55:37.568 8080-8080/com.republicera D/timeestart: 55
2019-09-17 08:55:37.568 8080-8080/com.republicera D/timeestart: 1568670922872
2019-09-17 08:55:37.568 8080-8080/com.republicera D/timeestart: 32400000
2019-09-17 08:55:37.568 8080-8080/com.republicera D/timeestart: 3300000
2019-09-17 08:55:37.568 8080-8080/com.republicera D/timeestart: 1568706622872
```

You can clearly see in logs 3,4 & 5 that each one of these variables have a value greater than 0, so why when I try to add them the value remains as the original value?

Comment: _"You can clearly see in logs 3,4 & 5 that each one of these variables have a value greater than 0"_ But what you're printing is `minute` and `hourOfDay`, not `startMinute` and `startHour`.

Comment: @Michael sorry, in my code I assign to `startMinute` and `startHour` the values of `hourOfDay` and `minute`. I removed it to simplify my post but forgot to edit that out of this one line. Fixed it now. I also checked the simplified version of course, the values are assigned properly.

Comment: But it's not the original value: 156*86709*22872 < 156*87066*22872. It's just very similar.

Comment: @adrianbukros OMG. I'm such an idiot. A bit dialectic so completely missed it every time i looked at it! Thank you for pointing that out to me I was loosing my mind.